# Laravel - property of non object error while logged out

Tags: laravel, validation, routes

My project is meant to display a users company name in the url, which works perfectly while logged in. However any view I apply the below solution to throws a property of non object error when you log out, which is because it's looking for auth::user company and can't find it.

I've tried a few things but can't get it working to redirect to login whilst still using the below solution. Is there a way to do this?

web.php code with error:

```
Route::get('/home/{company}', 'HomeController@index'); 
Route::get('/home',function(){
 return redirect('home/'.Auth::user()->company);
});
```

so when I sign out and the url is mywebsite/home I get the object error, but if I manually amend anything to the end of this it redirects. eg mywebsite/home/random

code that doesn't give error and redirects as expected:

```
 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Jonathons solution, with the auth::check but putting all routes through a group did the trick.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() { -- all routes in here --- });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Route::get('/home',function(){
    return redirect(Auth::check() ? 'home/'.Auth::user()->company : 'login');
});
```

This way, when a hitting the `/home` URL, the system will first check to see if there is a user logged in. If so, it will redirect to the logged in user's company page. If not, it will redirect to the login page. `Auth::check()` will return `true` if there is a user logged in, or `false` if not.

Comment: thanks, I will try that as well in case I need it for something specific, I think I found a more encompassing  solution using Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function()
{ -- all routes in here --- });

Answer (score 0):

try change your redirect for this

```
Route::get('/home/{company}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')

Route::get('/home',function(){
 return redirect()->route('home', \Auth::user()->company);
});
```

Comment: I used this to fix my problem: Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() { -- all routes in here --- }); but will try your solution as well, thanks.